How to call a web handler from a C# WinForms Application
Let me start by saying I tried the various examples I found, both here and elsewhere, and they didn't solve my issue.  SO, let me start over:
I have an ASP.NET Web Forms website that uses a number of web handlers to expose database functionality, and they are all secured in folders which require the user to be authenticated using the Microsoft MembershipProvider model.  This, obviously, is no issue if the site user is authenticated.
HOWEVER, my hosting company changed its policies for SQL Server so that my database cannot be accessed outside the site's domain, and I am writing an ASP.NET C# WinForms application for managing the site's data. My only option for accessing my database from the WinForms app is to make calls to the web handlers on the site, and as long as the web handlers are located in folders which don't require authenticated access then this works out fine.  But clearly I don't want the web handlers to be accessible to anyone who is not an authorized administrative user of the site, and I am struggling to figure out how to make my WebRequest or WebClient calls able to use Membership credentials to access the web handlers.
Everything I have tried in terms of examples has failed - they all "work" as long as the web handlers are in unsecured folders.  When I try to move the handlers to secured folders, the WebRequest or WebClient is redirected to the login page.
There is a class code sample I found that I am using, as follows:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace MCTDesk.Web {
    public enum httpVerb {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

    public enum authenticationType {
        Basic,
        NTLM
    }

    public enum autheticationTechnique {
        RollYourOwn,
        NetworkCredential
    }

    class RestClient {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }
        public authenticationType authType { get; set; }
        public autheticationTechnique authTech { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }


        public RestClient ( ) {
            endPoint = string.Empty;
            httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
        }

        public string makeRequest ( ) {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString ( );
            String authHeader = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + userPassword));
            request.Headers.Add ( "Authorization", authType.ToString ( ) + " " + authHeader );
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = ( HttpWebResponse ) request.GetResponse ( );
                //Proecess the resppnse stream... (could be JSON, XML or HTML etc..._
                using ( Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream ( ) ) {
                    if ( responseStream != null ) {
                        using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ( responseStream ) ) {
                            strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd ( );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex ) {
                strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString ( ) + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
            finally {
                if ( response != null ) {
                    ( ( IDisposable ) response ).Dispose ( );
                }
            }
            return strResponseValue;
        }
    }
}

Using this class, I have this code:
        private void LoadStats ( ) {
            RestClient rClient = new RestClient {
                endPoint = "https://[my site URL].com/handlers/gettodaystats.ashx",
                authTech = autheticationTechnique.RollYourOwn,
                authType = authenticationType.Basic,
                userName = "<uername>",
                userPassword = "<password>"
            };
            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            strResponse = rClient.makeRequest ( );
            MessageBox.Show ( strResponse );
        }

The code works fine as long as the web handler being called is in an unsecured folder.  As soon as I move the handler to a secured folder and call it, the result coming back is the HTML of the login page.
My last try at posting this question got rejected as "duplicate", but with everything suggested in other posts, nothing worked, so I am hoping someone will actually help with this.  What am I doing wrong here?

"ASP.NET Authentication" isn't really a thing. What type of authentication system do you have in place? Integrated Windows Authentication? OIDC? Basic?

The website uses basic authentication.

I googled "basic authentication httpclient" and got lots of results. Here's one from Stack Overflow. Though personally I prefer to use Flurl, which makes basic authentication easy.

If you already have an the Authentication Token then this works. If not then look into how to handle Basic Authentication using HttpClient.
            byte[] imageData = null;
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            //using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            //{
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
            imageData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);
}

I saw the comment about website using Basic Authentication
                     String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));

       byte[] imageData = null;
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            imageData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);
                }

